# Batch Script to Echo another batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file, echo

How can i do in batch file to echo (create) another batch file to run in windows start and delete it after running? [Trying WSl 2 installer with one batch script actually]

i tried this ,

```
@echo off
:: BatchGotAdmin
// asking one time admin priv code  here
@echo off
title wsl setup Part 1 ! 


dism.exe /online /enable-feature /featurename:Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux /all /norestart

dism.exe /online /enable-feature /featurename:VirtualMachinePlatform /all /norestart

// and here is my another batch to need echo correctly in C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\StartUp\ for run after reboot  
 
(echo @echo off^
:: BatchGotAdmin
// admin priv for  seconf batch  

@echo off
title wsl setup part 2 !

//other steps for download kernel and set default wsl version here

echo "Setup Finished, Deleting this bat" && del C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\StartUp\wsl-part2.bat && pause
) > "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\StartUp\wsl-part2.bat"


//First batch again for asking reboot now or later


:PROMPT
SET /P REBOOTNOW=Do you want reboot now second script will run after reboot (Y/[N])?
IF /I "%REBOOTNOW%" NEQ "N" GOTO END

shutdown -r


:END
endlocal
```

But i stucked dism commands loop (because echo is not understant it is a string) and echo only to target file

```
@echo off:: BatchGotAdmin
Requesting administrative privileges...
```

Comment: Why are you wanting to run a batch file on startup, which will try to self elevate then run an msi, a wsl.exe command and install a distro app. All of those are individual executables and can be run directly using more efficient methods.

Comment: @Compo Because i want single file which can install wsl single bat with single admn priv. It will like a any installer program which wants reboot then run after reboot once then kill startup own startup script. I can run with 2 seperate batch file for install wsl , then upgrade wsl 2 and run any distro what i want. Single file cooler than 2 file :)

Comment: It is not one fille, the first batch file is creating a second vbscript file, running it then deleting it, then writing a third batch file which probably creates a fourth vbscript file runs it then deletes it, before eventually deleting itself. So your 'cooler' one file is at least three files, possibly four, just made unnecessarily complicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite my comment to the contrary, if you wish to do this using such a complicated methodology, here's the general syntax for doing so:

```sh
(   Echo @Echo Off
    Echo Rem BatchGotAdmin
    Echo // admin priv for second batch  
    Echo Title WSL Setup Part 2.
    Echo // other steps for download kernel and set default WSL version here
    Echo Echo Setup Finished, deleting this script.
    Echo (GoTo^) 2^>Nul ^& Del "%%~f0"
) 1> "%ProgramData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\StartUp\wsl-part2.cmd"
```

You should note that I've changed the self deletion command, to something more efficient and functional. It decided to do that because it shows you that, using this method, you need to escape problematic characters with carets, *(including ampersands, redirection symbols, pipes, and closing parentheses)*. You also need to escape `%` characters by doubling them.

Comment: Thats good but every line need echo right? Can we write this in ps without echo every line ?

Comment: 'We' cannot write it! I've answered your question, so please mark it as accepted, you asked how to you 'Echo' another batch-file, and I've shown you exactly that! Please ask a new question in the appropriate manner if you have a different, and on topic, PowerShell coding issue. Apart from anything else, sticking to your 'cooler' one file theory, how are you going to run the PowerShell script, write it from a batch file, run it, and delete it?